# Error performing with OCR - Microsoft Azure Computer Vision API

Tags: azure, computer-vision

I am using Microsoft Azure Computer Vision for OCR PDF extraction. When i tried performing OCR it gives the error as

```
Read PDF With OCR: Error performing OCR: MicrosoftAzureComputerVisionErrorRunEngine
```

Can anyone support me in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

For this case, a possible reason is you may exceed the limitation of your current tier, like if you are using free tier, there is limit for the F0 tier subscription in the current monthly cycle (up to 5000 transactions)

As a note you can check the different tier limits and prices on the following documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

Another good suggestion I can make is for you to read through the following azure free account FAQs: https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/free/free-account-faq/ . Here you will get more details about the Pay as You Go account type.